# Beamer footnotes references with same number

Tags: beamer, biblatex

Is there any possibility that if in the same frame a reference is cited more than 1 time, give the same footnote number to it? In my MWE you see that there is two footnotes. But the bib entry is the same. Therefore, I want that it appears once and in the text the same number is given. Thus, in the MWE only one footnote should appear.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is text\footfullcite{westfahl:space}.
Here is text\footfullcite{westfahl:space}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not cite the second time but simply reinsert the footnotemark from the first time:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Here is text\footfullcite{Hillas}.
        Here is text\footnotemark[1].
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works somehow. However if they are not in sequence, you need to remember the number. I would like to have for example a reference, that you may use in `footnotemark` to have the correct number.